# while running this programe i occured one error as command not found

Tags: linux, bash

This is my program:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

read x y z

if [ `$x -eq $y` -o `$z -eq $y` -o `$z -eq $x` ]
then
    echo "ISOSCELES"
elif [ `"$x" -eq "$y"` -a `$y -eq $z` -a `$z -eq $x` ]
 
then
    echo "EQUILATERAL"
else
    echo "SCALENE"
    
fi
```

and this is question:

> Given three integers (X,Y, and Z) representing the three sides of a
> triangle, identify whether the triangle is scalene, isosceles, or
> equilateral.
>
> If all three sides are equal, output EQUILATERAL. Otherwise, if any
> two sides are equal, output ISOSCELES. Otherwise, output SCALENE.

I found this kind of error:

> command not found

Comment: Put #!/bin/bash -x to enable debugging and try to re-run again, maybe this will help to identify the issue

Comment: By the way, just noticed that you have a space in #! /bin/bash

Comment: no that us not a problem in bash script @TelinovDmitri

Comment: Did you see the extra ` after the second `-eq "$y"` ?

Comment: Paste your code into https://shellcheck.net and fix whatever pops up.

Comment: When `x == y` and `y == z` you do not need to check `z == x`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$x , $y , $z does not contain any valid bash command., basically ` is not required.

Instead of

```
if [ `$x -eq $y` ]
```

you need to use

```
if [ "$x" -eq "$y" ]
```

Answer (score 1):

You should check your input for positive integers.
I wrote the test for Isosceles as a multiplication: funnier, not better.

```
#!/bin/bash
read -p "Give the length of the 3 sides (as integers): " x y z

if (( x == y )) && (( y == z)); then
  echo "EQUILATERAL"
elif (( (x-y) * (y-z) * (z-x) == 0 )); then
  echo "ISOSCELES"
else
  echo "SCALENE"
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

Working example:

```
#!/bin/bash -x

read x y z

if [ "$x" -eq "$y" ] && [ "$y" -eq "$z" ]
then
    echo "EQUILATERAL"
elif [ "$x" -eq "$y" ] || [ "$z" -eq "$y" ] || [ "$z" -eq "$x" ]
then
    echo "ISOSCELES"
else
    echo "SCALENE"
fi
```

Output:

```
~# ./1.sh
+ read x y z
3 3 3
+ '[' 3 -eq 3 ']'
+ '[' 3 -eq 3 ']'
+ echo EQUILATERAL
EQUILATERAL

~# ./1.sh
+ read x y z
3 3 4
+ '[' 3 -eq 3 ']'
+ '[' 3 -eq 4 ']'
+ '[' 3 -eq 3 ']'
+ echo ISOSCELES
ISOSCELES

~# ./1.sh
+ read x y z
3 4 5
+ '[' 3 -eq 4 ']'
+ '[' 3 -eq 4 ']'
+ '[' 5 -eq 4 ']'
+ '[' 5 -eq 3 ']'
+ echo SCALENE
SCALENE
```

Comment: `[[ $x -eq $y && $y -eq $z && $z -eq $x ]]` can be reduced to `[[ $x -eq $y && $y -eq $z ]]`. Equality is transitive.

Comment: Don't both with `-eq` inside `[[ ... ]]`. Either use the POSIX-compliant `[ "$x" -eq "$y" ]` or the superior `bash` extension `(( x == y ))`.